# What is the error contract for functions from "fs" in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

In my app, written in JavaScript for Node, I wan't to try to recover from file system errors. In order to do that I need to know what that error can be. The manual doesn't [say](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) much. So my question is:

- **What is the contract for the error object? What can that error object be?**

Example:

```
readFile('file/path', function (error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

All errors returned are inherited from the JavaScript Error Object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error), and fall into two categories: JS errors and system errors.

Single operation APIs such as the readFile method in your example return either null, if there is no error, or an Error instance (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html). Common system errors such as Permission Denied or No Such File can be returned, and an exhaustive list can be found here:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html

There is plenty of documentation, you just need to be careful to catch the errors properly, especially when using async methods.

Errors are instances of the JS object and have properties. You can do something like:

```
    if (e.code === 'EISDIR') { 
        console.log("Is not a directory!"); 
    } else { 
        throw e; 
    }
```

Comment: fine, what is EISDIR? - a number or a string or an object?

Comment: It is an object, that is, an instance of JS Error object. It is with properties. You can do something like:  `if (e.code === 'EISDIR') {
  console.log("Is not a directory!");
} else {
  throw e;
}`

Comment: 'EISDIR' is just a string, error code, full list of possible error codes can be found there: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs here for the Node Error object.

[Error](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html)

Typically it'll have a message and stack property. The `message` property is a detailed message about the error that was thrown. `stack` is the stack trace at the point when the error was thrown.

Some developers also put custom properties to add more details about the error. Hope this helps.

Comment: i already did, didn't help as it doesn't specify what system errors are. what do you think they are: numbers, strings or objects?

Comment: According to the docs, "In Node.js, system errors are represented as augmented Error objects -- not full subclasses, but instead an error instance with added members." The docs provides all properties for system errors.

Comment: the original question was: What are those error objects.